# Marshal list of objects of different types with JAXB

Tags: spring, jaxb

I work with Spring and JAXB and want to marshal a list of different DTO Objects so
the required XML response should be like :

```
<root>
     <dto_list>
              <dto1>
                 <name>xxx</name>
              </dto1>
              <dto2>
                 <location>xxx</location>
              </dto2>
      </dto_list>
</root>
```

Assuming the Class Objects are:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Dto1")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Dto1 {

@XmlElement
private String name;
// setter/getters
}
```

and

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Dto2")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Dto2 {

@XmlElement
private String location;
// setter/getters
}
```

and the wrapper class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class DTOsWrapper {

private List<Object> dto;

public void setDto(List<Object> dto) {
  this.dto = dto;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name = "dto_list")
@XmlElements({
     @XmlElement(name = "dto1", type = Dto1.class),
     @XmlElement(name = "dto2", type = Dto2.class)
})
public List<Object> getDto() {
  return dto;
}
}
```

and the endpoint:

```
@RestController
public class DTOEndpoint {

@Autowired
private IDTOService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/restxml", produces = "application/xml")
public Object retrieveAllDTOs() {

  DTOsWrapper o = service.findDtos(); //returns a DTOsWrapper obj of a list containing Dto objs, i.e Dto1, Dto2 etc

  return o;
```

}

I get {"error": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Could not instantiate JAXBContext for class [class <>to.DTOsWrapper]: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions; anyone have a clue?

Comment: Could you post a code from a service, the portion which is creating a DTOsWrapper object?

Comment: @Override
     public DTOsWrapper findDtos() {
     List<Object> dtos = new ArrayList<>();

      dtos.addAll(EntryDAO.findDTOS1()); //returns a List<Dto1>
      dtos.addAll(EntryDAO.findDTOS2()); //returns a List<Dto2>

      DTOsWrapper mydtos = new DTOsWrapper();
      mydtos.setDto(dtos);
      return mydtos;

      }